# How to fix broken doctrine relations?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

There are two entities:

1. "Listings" that has the following ManyToOne relation:

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Catalog", inversedBy="Listings",)
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="catalog_id", referencedColumnName="catalog_id")
 */
protected $catalog;

This table already has some data

2. Now, after I imported some data manually to the Catalog table I would like to fix all the relations so the Listings table points to the right catalogs.

I wonder if there is any easy way to do it without iterating through all catalogs and listings.

Comment: iterating through all catalogs and listings. is the easy way, the hard way will be to clear your data and refill it again

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to fix your datas is to use a command that will fix them. You create a method in your repository with a limit if you have lot of entity to get corrupted datas then update. [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html)